# Different behavor of a tooptip for different mouse events in richfaces is possible?

Tags: jsf, tooltip, richfaces, popuppanel

Is there any way to make a tooptip behave differently deppending on if a mouse is over the element or it is clicked?

I need to have the same element working as a tooltip if the mouse is over and to open a popup panel if the mouse is clicked.

I could do it easily if using separated elements, but i need to use the same.

Comment: I don't understand. You put the mouse over an element -> tooltip appears. You click the mouse -> popup panel appears. What do you need the tooltip to do now?

Comment: For the same element (same image) I want when I put the mouse over the element behaves a tooltip, if I click on that, a popup panel appear. From the examples I get the documentation, I can have an element working as a tool tip and another element working as a popup caller, but I dont want to have 2 elements.

Comment: Can you add some code to your question? I still don't really get what you're trying to do. Show how it would look with the two elements, then we can work out how to change it to a single one.

Comment: It is already solved. The way I did was : put a rich tooltip inside a a4j commandlink, with a popup associated on click.